# Public API Bearer token acceso

Tags: api, swagger

Estoy iniciando en el tema de las API's, estoy probando una Public API, me otorgaron una llave y un usuario, al hacer la petición en POSTMAN (he probado varias formas de autorización) lo unico que me regresa es 401 error.

En la sección de autorización de la respuesta no autorizada me da lo siguiente: "www-authenticate": "Bearer authorization_uri=url_APIPublica" por lo que supongo que el método de autenticación es bearer, pero aun así, me pregunto por qué me dieron un usuario y llave.

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.